# Vimeo API missing files array in response

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to get the url of the MP4 file for a public video as a PRO user using Vimeo's API and [php library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php).

```
$lib = new Vimeo($apiKey, $apiSecret, $accessToken);
$response = $lib->request('/videos/' . $video_id);
var_dump($response['body']);
```

This is successfully giving me a response from the API, but it is missing the files array that should contain the link to the mp4 file (according to this [forum response](https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:129521)).

My access token has private, public and interact scopes. Any other reason the files array is missing?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else experiencing this, it may be caused by a missing 'Video Files' scope on the access token (starting from version 3.3+).

More info: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/issues/194

Answer (score 0):

PRO users only have access to their own videos. If the access token is authenticated as the owner of $video_id you should be able to see the files key.

If you are unable to see the files key, contact us at https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Comment: So funny story, somebody forgot to renew our PRO account, hence the missing files array. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I have a Business Live account is that the same? I am not getting files in the response.

Comment: Business live should have access. If you do not see them make sure you have the video_files scope on your token. If that doesn't help, reach out to vimeo.com/help/contact for more detailed support.